# Outlook 2010 list defaults closed

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I just installed outlook 2010 on my laptop after deciding I didn't like the visual style of 2013 when paired with Windows 7.

Anyway, I have two email account set up, and the second one that I added to outlook defaults minimized in the side bar.  It's not a huge problem, but I would really like to have both email accounts default to an expanded view.

I have tried to expand the bottom account, but every time I restart outlook it's minimized again.

Is there a setting somewhere that I can change so it defaults expanded.

Here's a photo of what I'm talking about.

[image]

And this is how I would like it to default.

[image]

Comment: +1 for providing an excellent example and desired outcome. I also removed your e-mail address in your screenshots to prevent unwanted e-mails.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't quite sure how to verbalize the issue - I thought the photo would make it easier.  Also, thanks for removing my email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Outlook will keep your second inbox expanded. Reasons that it may not are when:

- Outlook has not fully closed (outlook.exe still in task manager). This may be due to Lync being open, sync software running, etc.
- Your second inbox connected to the mail server via IMAP

If Outlook does not expand your second inbox by default, you can run a [Outlook VBA script to expand all the folders](http://vboffice.net/sample.html?lang=en&mnu=2&smp=57&cmd=showitem) during startup.

Full explanation here on [starting Outlook with folders collapsed or expanded](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/595)